# python: how to count number in one file?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I need to write a Python program to read the values in a file, one per line, such as file: test.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Denoting these as **j1, j2, j3, ... jn**,
I need to sum the differences of consecutive values:

```
a=(j2-j1)+(j3-j2)+...+(jn-j[n-1])
```

I have example source code

```
    a=0
    for(j=2;j<=n;j++){
    a=a+(j-(j-1))
    }
print a
```

and the output is

```
9
```

Comment: python doesn't use curly braces, what is your example code?

Comment: what is `jn`, is it the number on a line from the test.txt?

Comment: I don't understand anything about your question, and it is not because of your English.

Comment: You maths don't quite add up

Comment: You are simply summing the row differences.  In your example, the difference of each row is 1 and would sum to 9.

Comment: Why don't you just subtract the value on the 1st line from the value on the last, IOW, `jn - j1`? All the values from the other lines get cancelled out. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: Clarified explanation.  I did not correct the errors in the supposed example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following equation;

```
a = (j2-j1) + (j3-j2) + ... + (jn-(jn-1))
```

As you iterate over the file, it will subtract the value in the previous line from the value in the current line and then add all those differences.

```
a = 0

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    previous = next(f).strip()
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue
        a = a + (int(line) - int(previous))
        previous = line

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution (Python 3)**

```
res = 0
with open("test.txt","r") as fp:
    lines = list(map(int,fp.readlines()))
    for i in range(1,len(lines)):
        res += lines[i]-lines[i-1]
print(res)
```

**Output**: `9`

`test.text` contains:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure if I understand the question, but here's my best attempt at solving what I think is your problem:

1. To read values from a file, use "with open()" in read mode ('r'):

   `with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
       -your code here-`
2. "as f" means that "f" will now represent your file if you use it anywhere in that block
3. So, to read all the lines and store them into a list, do this:

   `all_lines = f.readlines()`

You can now do whatever you want with the data.

4. If you look at the function you're trying to solve, a=(j2-j1)+(j3-j2)+...+(jn-(jn-1)), you'll notice that many of the values cancel out, e.g. (j2-j1)+(j3-j2) = j3-j1. Thus, the entire function boils down to jn-j1, so all you need is the first and last number.

Edit: That being said, please try and search this forum first before asking any questions. As someone who's been in your shoes before, I decided to help you out, but you should learn to reference other people's questions that are identical to your own.

Comment: sorry. my fault. the output is 10. not 2

Comment: The output should actually be 9 based on your function.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is 9 :

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    # set prev to first number in the file
    prev = int(next(f))
    sm = 0
    # iterate over the remaining numbers
    for j in f:
        j = int(j)
        sm += j - prev
        # update prev 
        prev = j
    print(sm)
```

Or using *itertools.tee* and *zip*:

```
from itertools import tee
with open("data.txt") as f:
    a,b = tee(f)
    next(b)
    print(sum(int(j) - int(i) for i,j in zip(a, b)))
```